# Find equations of specific lines lies on a saddle shaped 3d surface

Tags: multivariable-calculus, analytic-geometry

I have equations for saddle-shaped surface (likely hyperbolic paraboloid) in $3D$ space. [Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdJmQ.png)

In such cases, I want to know the equations of two lines which are,

1. Lies on the surface of the given equation
2. has constant $z$

For example, for the following values,

$z = a + bx + cy + dxy+ex^2+fy^2$

$ a = 1.3907,$

$b = -0.087591,$

$c = -0.25811,$

$d = 0.033397,$

$e = 0.0027985,$

$f = 0.00089385 $

The shape of the surface and such line would be like [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOfsW.png) ( [wolfram alpha link for the surface](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=z+%3D+1.3907+-+0.087591x+-0.25811y+%2B+0.033397xy+%2B++0.0027985x%5E2+%2B+0.00089385y%5E2) )

How can I get an equation of such a line?

Comment: A line may not have constant $z$. In this case, it could be any conic.

Comment: @AnubhabGhosal Yes, there could be many lines over the given surface with non-constant z. However, my question is, I want to know only the equation of lines having constant z on the surface of the given equation. And according to my instinct, (of course, it could be wrong) There would be only two lines if given surface is kind of hyperbolic paraboloid.

Comment: All contours(curves with constant z) are conics in this case. The condition that the contour is a pair of straight lines can be found by equating the discriminant to 0.

Comment: @AnubhabGhosal Thank you for your answer. However, unfortunately, I don't know how to calculate discriminant on a multivariate case. Where can I find relevant information? In addition, If it is okay for you, may I ask you how can I find the saddle point of the given hyperbolic surface? Sorry for bothering you since I'm not good at math.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1742848/what-is-condition-for-second-degree-equation-to-represent-a-pair-of-straight-lin

Comment: @AnubhabGhosal Thank you so much for your kind answer!

Comment: @AnubhabGhosal In the context of conic sections, “discriminant” doesn’t usually refer the the entire $3\times3$ determinant, which is what we need to examine to determine degeneracy.

Comment: @amd, afaik, it does. See https://brilliant.org/wiki/conics-discriminant/

Comment: @AnubhabGhosal For every expert there exists an equal and opposite expert. Search for “discriminant of conic sections.” The vast majority of hits use it for the discriminant of the quadratic part, as does the main Wikipedia article. Note that the article you cite also calls $B^2-4AC$ the equation’s discriminant just a few lines down from the top, though it later qualifies it with “quadratic.”

Comment: @amd, I see. Anyhow, I hope the OP understood what I meant.